# Why is $5\tan(54^\circ) = \sqrt{25 + 10\sqrt{5}}$ and $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right) = \sqrt{5 - 2\sqrt{5}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, radicals, nested-radicals

On the [Wikipedia Page about Pentagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon), I noticed a statement in their work saying that $\sqrt{25+10\sqrt{5}}=5\tan(54^{\circ})$ and $\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}=\tan(\frac {\pi}{5})$

My question is: How would you justify that? My goal is to simplify $\sqrt{25+10\sqrt{5}}$ and $\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}$ without knowledge on the detested radical!

Comment: I feel this would be hard to show without Calc but I could be wrong.

Comment: The only way I know how to do this is using roots of unity

Comment: The common angles of a regular pentagon are $108$. If you draw a diagonal between two vertices you get an isosceles triangle with angles $108-36-36$.  Using this triangle you can get the trigonometric functions of $36=90-54$.

Comment: Can we use $\tan5x$ formula?

Comment: Wait, there's a formula to this?!? What's the formula?

Comment: @Frank:  There is everything in the vineyard of the Lord:                $$\tan (5x)=\frac{\sin (x)(1-12\cos^2(x)+16\cos^4(x))}{\cos^5(x)-10\cos^3(x)\sin^2(x)+5\cos (x)\sin^4(x)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You surely know that $z=\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}$ is the root in the first quadrant of $z^5-1=0$ so it satisfies
$$
z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0
$$
that can also be written as
$$
z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}+z+\frac{1}{z}+1=0
$$
or, by noting that $z^2+1/z^2=(z+1/z)^2-2$,
$$
\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2+\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)-1=0
$$
Therefore,
$$
z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}
$$
Thus
$$
\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4},
\qquad
\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}=\sqrt{1-\frac{5-2\sqrt{5}+1}{16}}=
\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{4}
$$
Now use that
$$
\tan\frac{x}{2}=\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}
$$
and you get
$$
\tan\frac{\pi}{5}=\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{3+\sqrt{5}}=
\frac{\sqrt{(10+2\sqrt{5})(3-\sqrt{5})^2}}{4}=
\frac{\sqrt{80-32\sqrt{5}}}{4}=\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}
$$

Since $54^\circ=3\pi/10=\pi/2-\pi/5$, we have
$$
\tan\frac{3\pi}{10}=\cot\frac{\pi}{5}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}}=
\sqrt{\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{25-20}}=\frac{\sqrt{25+10\sqrt{5}}}{5}
$$

Comment: Wait, isn't $\left(z+\frac {1}{z}\right)^2=z^2+\frac {1}{z^2}+2$?

Comment: @Frank Rats! Switched side! Fixed

Comment: @egreg, Are things easier if we play with $\tan?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee No, if you start with $\infty$

Comment: I'm kind of confused on one thing: How did you know to use the function $z^5-1=0$?

Comment: @Frank De Moivre's formula

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @N.F.Taussig for pointing out some errors.

Suppose you have a regular pentagon, with vertices $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$ (labelled cyclically so $A$ is neighbor to $B$ and $E$).  Let us take each side length to be $1$.  Let $X$ be the length of a diagonal, say $AC$.  Let's first compute $X$.

[image: regular_pentagon]

To do it, let $P$ be the intersection of $AC$ and $BE$. Now we do some easy angle chasing:  $\angle{BCA}=36=\angle{BAC}$, $\angle{CBP}=72=\angle{CPB}$. $\angle{ABP}=36$. Of course $\Delta BPC$ is isosceles (though not similar) and this implies that $PC$ has length $1$ We also see that $\Delta ABP$ is isosceles with angles $108-36-36$.  Thus it is similar to $\Delta ACB$. Similarity then lets us compute $X$:  $$\frac {X-1}1=\frac 1X\implies X^2-X-1=0\implies X=\frac 12(1+\sqrt5)$$

Now drop the perpendicular from $P$ to $AB$, let $Q$ denote its foot. Clearly $\Delta PAQ$ is a right triangle with angles $90-36-54$.  We know one leg ($\frac 12$) and the hypotenuse ($\frac 12 (\sqrt 5 -1 )$).  That suffices to solve the triangle and gives you the answer you seek.

Comment: Based on my diagram, which I could post, it looks like you meant $\angle C\color{red}{P}B = 72^\circ$ rather than $\angle CDB$.   Also, $\triangle ABP$ is isosceles with angles $108^\circ - 36^\circ - 36^\circ$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You are absolutely correct on both counts...poor $D$ hasn't even got anything to do with the picture, not sure how he snuck in.  Will edit accordingly.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the diagram which helped me catch the now corrected errors.  You can add diagrams by clicking on the mountain, then following the instructions.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  What did you use to draw the figure?  I made one that I exported to .pdf but I couldn't see how to embed it here.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Thanks, by the way.  The figure really helps.  I note, for the record, that on my paper, no one alive could distinguish $P$ from $D$.  Sad, really.

Comment: I drew the figure with the LaTeX drawing program [tikz](http://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf).  It is a powerful program, but there is a learning curve.  Fortunately, I had made a version of the diagram, which I just had to relabel.

Answer (score 1):

As $54\cdot5\equiv90\pmod{180},$

if $\tan5x=\infty,5x=180^\circ n+90^\circ$ where $n$ is any integer

$x=36^\circ n+18^\circ$ where $n\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2\pmod5$

Using $\tan5x$ [expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html), the roots of $$5t^4-10t^2+1=0$$ are $\tan(36^\circ n+18^\circ)$  where $n\equiv0,\pm1,2\pmod5$

as $n=2\implies\tan(36^\circ n+18^\circ)=?$

$$t^2=\dfrac{10\pm4\sqrt5}{2\cdot5}=\dfrac{5\pm2\sqrt5}5$$

As $\tan54^\circ>\tan18^\circ>0,\tan^254^\circ>\tan^218^\circ,$

$\tan^254^\circ=\dfrac{5+2\sqrt5}5=\dfrac{25+10\sqrt5}{5^2}$
and $\tan^218^\circ=\dfrac{25-10\sqrt5}{5^2}$

For $\tan36^\circ,$ can you use the same idea?